# How to include public repository in maven packaging

Tags: java, maven

I m referring [repository](https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public) in my Maven project and i mentioned it in my `pom.xml` like following:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo2</id>
        <name>your custom repo</name>
        <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Now I am able to run my program in eclipse i.e. locally but if i build a jar package and deploy it somewhere it will not work because it did not find the dependency.

Now my question is how to package all dependency also i need to mentioned those dependency in class-path(manifest file)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a self-contained uber-jar using [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html). It will shade all the dependencies into the jar and will not require additional libraries on the class path:

> The Shade Plugin has a single goal:
>
> `shade:shade` is bound to the package phase and is used to create a shaded jar.